# Не получается установить элементы, как на скриншоте

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

Коллеги, подскажите, пожалуйста. Не получается сверстать L так, как на скрине.
Нужно сделать с помощью flex Буква состоит из 2 svg изображений. И объясните, пожалуйста, как организовать данную задачу.

[image: ри]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: проще будет если это будет одно svg изображения а не 2

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример вёрстки с использованием данных фигур в виде SVG-изображения.

Скачайте по ссылке и пользуйтесь на здоровье.

Можно масштабировать как Вам будет угодно.

P.S. Результат смотрите на CodePen. При выполнении кода **здесь на сайте почему-то картинку не подгружает**.

https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/bGbKZpP

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: url("http://hisbvdis-pic.zzz.com.ua/drafts/zl.svg") center no-repeat, #519FCA;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как будет на svg буква L
Чтобы менять цвет заливки фигуры используется атрибут fill сейчас fill='black'

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg  version="1.1" width="1280" height="1024"
        viewBox="0 0 1280 1024"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
           
 <g >
  <rect width='50' height='200' fill='black'  x='300' y='150'  />
   <polygon points='300,370 300,400 450,400 420,370'/>
 </g>

 </svg>
```